# Incorrect increments/decrements on JS counter

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS and working on this counter that increments/decrements value when clicked, for e.g. the current value is 6 and if I decrement it , it goes 7,6,5 and so on

HTML:

```
<div id="add">Add</div>
<span id="text">0</span>    
<div id="red">Reduce</div>
```

JS:

```
var add  = document.getElementById("add");

var text  = document.getElementById("text");
var count = 1;

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
    text.innerText = count++;
});

red.addEventListener("click", function() {
    text.innerText = count--;
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is *red* defined or initialised? Don't rely on element IDs defining global variables, it's a legacy quirk that really should have been obsoleted years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [JS increment decrement](https://codeburst.io/javascript-increment-and-decrement-8c223858d5ed) operators in correct way

```js
var add = document.getElementById("add");

var text = document.getElementById("text");
var count = 0;

add.addEventListener("click", function() {

  text.innerText = ++count;
});

red.addEventListener("click", function() {

  text.innerText = --count;

});
```

```html
<div id="add">Add</div>
<span id="text">0</span>
<div id="red">Reduce</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-
Assign count to 0, and use pre-increment and pre-decrement operators. then assign

```
var add  = document.getElementById("add");

var text  = document.getElementById("text");
var count = 0;

add.addEventListener("click", function() {

text.innerText = ++count;
});

red.addEventListener("click", function() {

text.innerText = --count;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Increment/Decrements the value first then assign it

```js
var add = document.getElementById("add");
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var count = 0;

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  count += 1
  text.innerText = count;
});
red.addEventListener("click", function() {
  count -= 1
  text.innerText = count;

});
```

```html
<div id="add">Add</div>
<span id="text">0</span>
<div id="red">Reduce</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the counter to 0. Then instead of using *post-increment/post-decrement* *use pre-increment/pre-decrement*.

> If used prefix with operator before operand (for example, ++x), then it returns the value after incrementing.
>
> If used prefix (for example, --x), then it returns the value after decrementing.

```js
var add  = document.getElementById("add");

var text  = document.getElementById("text");
var count = 0;

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  text.innerText = ++count;
});

red.addEventListener("click", function() {
  text.innerText = --count;
});
```

```css
#add{
  color: green; 
  width: 60px; 
  border: 1px solid green; 
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#red{
  color: red; 
  width: 60px; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="add">Add</div>
<span id="text">0</span>    
<div id="red">Reduce</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that your `count` variable starts at 1 while your `<span>` text starts at 0. You want these values to be same.

Secondly, you should switch your increment/decrement to perform the increment and decrement before assigning it the `text.innerText` value (i.e. pre-incrementing). This can be done as follows:

```
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
    text.innerText = ++count; // See how the ++ comes beforehand
});

red.addEventListener("click", function() {
    text.innerText = --count; // See how the -- comes beforehand
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its refer to operator priority. Your following code:

```
text.innerText = count++;
```

Means:
    1: text.innerText = count;
    2: count = count + 1;

But the following line :

```
 text.innerText = ++count;
```

Means:
    1: count = count + 1;
    2: text.innerText = count;

See this for more result : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence